Adding Custom Description Input Field Next to File Names in FilePond
I'm using FilePond for file uploads in my Django project. I want to add a custom description input field next to each file name in the list of files to be uploaded. When I use the following HTML, the description fields appear but they are outside the FilePond design. This way, I can upload files, but I can't add a custom input field next to the file name within the FilePond structure.
Here is the HTML I'm using:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FilePond File Upload</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .filepond--item {
            width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{% url 'upload_file' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file-upload-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" class="filepond" name="file">
            <div id="description-container"></div>
            <button type="button" id="upload-button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-validate-type/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-type.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Register the plugins
        FilePond.registerPlugin(
            FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
            FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
        );

        // Set FilePond global options
        FilePond.setOptions({
            maxFileSize: '100KB',
            credits: false,
            allowMultiple: true,
            maxFiles: 50,
            server: {
                process: {
                    url: '{% url "upload_file" %}',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    onload: (response) => {
                        console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response);
                    }
                }
            },
            instantUpload: false  // Disable automatic upload
        });

        // Turn all file input elements into ponds
        const pond = FilePond.create(document.querySelector('.filepond'), {
            onaddfile: (error, fileItem) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Oh no');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('File added', fileItem);

                // Create a description input for each file
                const descriptionContainer = document.getElementById('description-container');
                const descriptionInput = document.createElement('textarea');
                descriptionInput.setAttribute('class', 'form-control mt-2');
                descriptionInput.setAttribute('name', 'descriptions');
                descriptionInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Description');
                descriptionInput.setAttribute('data-file-id', fileItem.id);
                descriptionContainer.appendChild(descriptionInput);
            },
            onremovefile: (error, fileItem) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Oh no');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('File removed', fileItem);

                // Remove the corresponding description input
                const descriptionContainer = document.getElementById('description-container');
                const descriptionInputs = descriptionContainer.querySelectorAll('textarea');
                descriptionInputs.forEach(input => {
                    if (input.getAttribute('data-file-id') === fileItem.id) {
                        descriptionContainer.removeChild(input);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Upload button click handler
        document.getElementById('upload-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Add descriptions to FormData
            const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('file-upload-form'));
            const descriptionContainer = document.getElementById('description-container');
            const descriptionInputs = descriptionContainer.querySelectorAll('textarea');
            descriptionInputs.forEach(input => {
                formData.append('descriptions', input.value);
            });

            // Process files manually
            pond.processFiles().then(() => {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '{% url "upload_file" %}');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
                xhr.onload = () => {
                    console.log('Files uploaded successfully:', xhr.responseText);
                };
                xhr.send(formData);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

When I select files, the description fields appear, but they are outside the FilePond design. I can upload files, but I cannot add a custom input field within the FilePond structure next to the file name.
Question: How can I add a custom description input field for each file within the FilePond structure so that it appears next to the file name in the FilePond design?
